# Approach how to use typescript with sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, jsom, typescript

What is the best approach to work with jsom in typescript on sharepoint 2010 platform ? I founded [defined types](https://github.com/gandjustas/sptypescript) but they based on sharepoint 2013 version and I don't know how much they are compatible with 2010 version.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed right version for sharepoint 2010.

```
"@types/sharepoint": "2010.0.29"
```